# how to pipe 2 commands to get my country IP address?

Tags: linux, bash

It's a very very basic question:
I have **geoiplookup** installed

And this command gives me my IP address: 
**wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO -**

How to pipe them together so I can get the country of my IP ?

I tried:

```
geoiplookup < wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO -
```

and

```
wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO - > geoiplookup
```

with no success. I know it is very basic question so I am quite ashamed to aks for answer here

Comment: You don't actually need to do 2 lookups - http://ipinfo.io can give you all the data you need. See http://ipinfo.io/developers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `-` after `-O` option of `wget` to print the result on STDOUT:

```
wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO -
```

then you can use:

```
geoiplookup -i "$(wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO -)"
```

Comment: geoiplookup < <(wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO -)
Usage: geoiplookup [-d custom_dir] [-f custom_file] [-v] [-i] <ipaddress|hostname>

Comment: @yarek check my edits

Comment: @heemayl : Thanks for reminding about `-`

Comment: @sjsam No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
 wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO - | geoiplookup -i
```

or

You could use the backticks like

```
geoiplookup -i `wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO -`
```

Yet another alternative is below :

```
curl ipinfo.io/`wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO -` | grep country
```

Comment: wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO - | geoiplookup
Usage: geoiplookup [-d custom_dir] [-f custom_file] [-v] [-i] <ipaddress|hostname>

Comment: @yarek : Yet another alternative is to use the combination of `curl` and `wget` like I have shown in the edit.